# Getting error even after datetime module while executing a practice code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from datetime import *
import os
stats=os.stat('aaa.txt')
print('File size in bytes:',stats.st_size)
print('File last Accessed Time:',datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime))
print('File last Modified Time:',datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_mtime))
```

Even after importing datetime module I'm getting error like

```
File size in bytes: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Directories/datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime import *
  File "F:\Python\Directories\datetime.py", line 5, in <module>
    print('File last Accessed Time:',datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime))
NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined
```

After editing the import statement as:-

```
import datetime
```

(instead of)

```
from datetime import *
```

I'm getting below error

```
File size in bytes: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/Directories/datetime.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "F:\Python\Directories\datetime.py", line 6, in <module>
    print('File last Accessed Time:',datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime))
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

Comment: In the second case it should be `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`.

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` and then `datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_mtime)` does not work?

Comment: I tried doing datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp earlier as well but it's throwing the same AttributeError

Answer (score 4):

You've named your module `datetime`, which is shadowing the stdlib `datetime`. `from datetime import *` is then importing everything *from itself*, which does not include an object named `datetime`, leading to the `NameError`.

Change the name of your module.

---

Import paths in Python are specified (in order) by `sys.path`. `sys.path[0]` is always `'.'`, aka the current working directory.

Effectively this means if you create a file with a `.py` extension that has the same name as a standard library package/module, that it will supersede the stdlib one and your `import`s from that package will prefer your module versus the stdlib module.

In your specific case, your `datetime.py` ran `from datetime import *` and attempted to import everything from itself, not from stdlib `datetime`. Python is smart enough to not re-run import statements for already-loaded modules, or else you'd get an infinite loop where your module imports itself, which sees that it should import itself so it imports itself, which sees that it should import itself so it imports itself, which sees....

However not falling into an infinite loop doesn't help when you try to actually *do* something with your `datetime` import, since you're expecting to see the stdlib `datetime` with all its associated members, but instead you're only seeing what you've already defined inside your own `datetime.py`!

Comment: Hey could you pls elaborate how could I change my name of module

Comment: Like import datetime as xyz

Comment: @PrashantKumar rename your python file.

Comment: Thanks Adam for bearing with me... I've changed my python file name but again its throwing    AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'

Comment: @PrashantKumar the module `datetime` doesn't. Switch it back to your `from datetime import *` format (or use `import datetime; datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`)

Comment: File size in bytes: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\Directories\dt.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "F:\Python\Directories\datetime.py", line 4, in <module>
    print('File last Accessed Time:',datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(stats.st_atime))
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'

Comment: I've used datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp after using import datetime but still getting error

Comment: Remove the `datetime.pyc` maybe? Your traceback doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Or do you still have the `datetime.py` file and you just made a new one called `dt.py`? That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Yes Adam I had that. I deleted everything and made a new file with different name and now it is executing fine. Thanks for the help....it had issues with the file name.... Could you pls explain once again why so as I am a beginner...

Comment: @PrashantKumar hopefully my edit clarified the problem.